# How to send mass email to my users and get a response from the mail server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, .net-4.5

I'm sending emails to about 10,000 of our registered users.  In the past we have had issues of not all of the emails being sent out.  I spoke to the mail server admin and he suggested I get a distinct code that is generated by the mail server to track each email sent.

I get my list of users from our oracle db and then loop through one at a time and do a `SmtpClient.Send()`. With `SmtpClient.Send()` I'm not sure how to get the mail server response back.  Is this possible with `Send()` or should I use one of the other `SmtpClient` methods of sending email that will return a response?

Comment: I don't know about receiving a code. But sending 10K emails at once could overwhelm servers or make it look like you're spamming. You might consider "chunking" the emails into smaller batches and sending them out over a larger time frame.

Comment: I would ask your mail server admin what he means there is no kind of identifier or tracking code generated when sending email via SMTP.

Comment: Actually, if Send method passed without Exception, you can't do much. It's mean that message successfully delivered to Smtp server, and now it's Smtp server responsibility to deliver message(sometimes it may take time), but you are not able to track it on your side

Comment: He showed me that the smtp server generates a result when a email is received and within that result he said there is an identifiable code.  In your opinions what would be the best way to ensure that all the emails are sent to the mail server correctly?  What is the cleanest approach with .net 4.5?  Thank you

Comment: I think your admin is thinking of the literal SMTP protocol (e.g. `250 Message Received`). The "Received" is simply a handshake back from the server letting the client know it understood the request and can process it (not that the end-user has received the email). Your SmtpClient library understands this and implicitly continues on (or exceptions out when the ACK fails).

Comment: Ask the admin for the detail of what the server returns. I don't see a way for the SMTP protocol to return, say, a message identifier.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, talk to your mail provider and look for any throttles/limits they have in place (a lot do to prevent spamming, especially if you're only paying for a corporate mailbox). If they have limits, build those into your send module. If they don't, it's probably still a good idea to send out batches of emails to avoid any silent failures.

As an aside, a company I worked for used to mass-mail to current and potential customers. We found it helpful to subscribe to a service like MailGun to send out emails for a few reasons:

- These services are meant to handle email. If you're only going one task, chances are you're doing it very well.
- A service provider follows [CAN-Spam](http://business.ftc.gov/documents/bus61-can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business) (giving you better chances of avoiding the blacklist).
- The service also used a different domain, so if we were blocked by companies we could still carry on with business transactions ("I never received your invoice" -- "that's because you spammed us last month and we blocked you!")
- As an added bonus, these services usually provide campaign management/analytics (why not get feedback while you're at it).

Comment: Brad I did ask my supervisor to go with an outside company to handle the email list.  He wasn't too keen on the idea.  So what I did was I created a wait function to pause the email process for 5 seconds for every 500 emails sent.  I tested it last night and I received all 5,000 emails as expected.  I'm doing it now for 10,000 to see if I receive all of them.  If so then that is the approach I will use.  Thank you everyone for all your help and suggestions.

Comment: @user3523871: Glad to hear it. Though, FWIW, MailGun does offer <= 10k emails as part of it's free tier. but whatever you decide to chose is your decision. Best of luck! (Though make sure that if they get blacklisted some time in the future you have a proud "I told you so" moment. ;-)

Comment: Brad, Thank you for mentioning MailGun.  That looks like a piece of software I can incorporate into my web page.  I might try out the free trial just for testing if I can get it to work properly.  Thanks again.

Comment: Would using a win forms application work as good as a console app?  There are many options I want to add before sending the email.  I was thinking of using a background worker to send the emails and display how many are being send to the UI.  Do you see any problems with this approach?  Thank you

Comment: @user3523871: Up to you, but either can email.